# Android 7.1 Write to text file

Tags: text, permissions, android-7.0-nougat

Guys New to Nougat come from Jelly bean Trying to write to sdcard a text file I know I now have to request permissions but cant find any code that works

Tried the following

```
        StringBuilder bodyStr=new StringBuilder();
                 bodyStr.append(data1Str.toString()).append(",").append(data2Str.toString()).append(",").append(data3Str.toString()).append(",").append(data4Str.toString()).append(",").append(data5Str.toString()).append(",").append(data22Str.toString()).append(",").append(data23Str.toString()).append(lineSep);; 
             String bodytextStr=bodyStr.toString();

                boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(data_entry.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (!hasPermission) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(data_entry.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
                }


                try {

                    File myFile = new File(fileName);
                    myFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                            new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutWriter.append(bodytextStr);
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comes back [permission denied]

have set usual permissions in manifest

any ideas where i'm going wrong

Any help Appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have the permission and can do the try catch block where you write into the file or you have to do it in the onRequestPermissionsResult.

Something like :

```
public void yourMethod(){
    boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(data_entry.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if(hasPermission){
      // write
    }else{
      // ask the permission
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(data_entry.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
      // You have to put nothing here (you can't write here since you don't
      // have the permission yet and requestPermissions is called asynchronously)
   }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    // The result of the popup opened with the requestPermissions() method
    // is in that method, you need to check that your application comes here
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // write
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest that you check this link : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: sorry I still get permission denied what I cant get is te same activity has a method that saves a picture taken with the camera and it saves it to the pictures directory fine but when I try the same with text its says permission denied

Comment: I Put a Toast in the yourMethod and it is going to ask the permission code in the else section but doesnt set the permission

Comment: If you have any doubt on the permission you already have, you can check in the settings of the device in the section about the application (applications management or something like that) and check for you application : there must be a "Permissions" section. What do you have there?

Comment: contacts,location, storage & telephoen

Comment: Are they checked? Did you get a popup like this : http://images.techtimes.com/data/images/full/162584/android-6-0-marshmallow-app-permissions.jpg ? The method requestPermissions() should open it

Comment: I dont get the allow popoup but all the permision switches are turned on for the app

Comment: What API do you target? Is it a fresh install or an updated one?

Comment: Are you sure that your filename is ok too?

Comment: API target is 25 (7.1.1) and flename is fine as if I install on jellybean it saves file fine it is an existing project that I wrote for jelly bean

Comment: Tanks for the help sebastian your code worked fine it was ny damn fault I had the write permissions in the wrong place inside the application. put it outside and it works thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/scoped-directory-access.html#accessing

You have to ask the user to give the rights to access it.

Comment: i think the problem is Im requesting access but the request box is not coming up