# Abort due to constraint violation

Tags: android

I am trying to edit a library in `/data/data/` from within that apps apk itself, internally, but am getting this

> 'Abort due to constraint violation'
>
> Error Code : 2067 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
>
> Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
>
> (UNIQUE constraint failed: directory.path (code 2067))

error. Can someone help please? Please refer to image and/or code.

```
public void startInjection(){ //class MainActivity
    String dataDir = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;

    String libPath = "/lib/libil2cpp.so";

    Inject.InjectNow(dataDir + libPath);
}

public static void InjectNow(String lib) { //class Inject
    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(lib, "rw");

        Inject.write(0x10614A, "0100A0E3");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TEST");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code and error as text. You can use a picture to show the directory hierarchy.

Comment: Not a problem. Updated.

Comment: Has your app [requested the permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40467835/150978) to access the sdcard section?

Comment: Yes it has.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>